# Run 'sudo mysql start' at boot time

Tags: boot, mysql

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and mysql 5.6

Each time after the server reboots, MySQL service fails to start automatically. I've determine this by checking the directory: `/var/run/mysqld/` and there is no `mysqld.sock`, however when I run the command `sudo service mysql status`, it shows that MySQL is running!!!

I have to restart MySQL with `sudo service mysql restart`, and then suddenly `mysqld.sock` and the `.pid` file will be generated, and `mysql` starts working.

Every time after boot I have to run this command manually.
I have created custom command in startup applications but it's not working.

Comment: What custom command did you try?

Comment: 'Sudo service mysql start' - the same command

Comment: Try `sudo service mysql enable && sudo service mysql start`  Enable adds it to the init service runlevel, a.k.a. systemd, and the start starts it for the current session.  If the command returns that the service is already enabled the status is correct.

Comment: Its giving this result  - `Usage: /etc/init.d/mysql start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status`

Comment: Wow, I would have thought the systemd syntax was now valid.  Try Sachin's Answer.

Comment: @eyoung100 Real systemd syntax would have been `systemctl enable mysql && systemctl start mysql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

Comment: do i need to use this as boot command?

Comment: Really thanks a lot , its working like a charm.... although it  takes some time in phpmyadmin . I just prepared myself to reinstall ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Good to know it helped you.